# What is replacing my ' and " characters in javascript code with &#39; and &quot;?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, escaping

Source (.Net 3.5)

```
  output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick, "alert(\"In order to prevent loss of your work, you may only use the progress grids within the same section.\");return false");
```

Rendered in browser:

```
<a onclick="alert(&quot;In order to prevent loss of your work, you may only use the progress grids within the same section.&quot;);return false" href="myPage.aspx#1">
```

This means that the JavaScript won't execute.

Similarly, if I replace the internal quotes with single quotes, it's escaped as '

Running on IIS version 7

It seems to be browser independent (IE 8,9 FF 15, Safari 7, Chrome)

It's either IIS, or the .Net config that's causing this to happen.

Of course, the funny thing is that It worked fine last night, and is now broken.

Is there any way to suppress this behavior?

Comment: Well, you call a method with an arguments containing quotes and they get escaped according to HTML rules ... I wonder what method might be responsible for doing so ...

Answer (score 0):

> This means that the JavaScript won't execute.

No, it doesn't. It prevents `"` characters in the data from terminating the HTML attribute value.

The HTML parser will decode the HTML into text (turning `&quot;` into `"` and so on) and pass that to the JavaScript parser.

> Is there any way to suppress this behavior?

Set the third argument (`fEncode`) to [`AddAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153285.aspx) to be false. This will **break** your HTML (and thus your script).

Comment: Yep. The Javascript code should still execute perfectly fine.